# Define a BitStruct inside a BitStruct in python using construct package

Tags: python

I am trying to read the following format (`Intel -> Little-Endian`):

```
X: 0 -> 31, size 32 bits
Offset: 32 -> 43, size 12 bits
Index: 44 -> 47, size 4 bits
Time: 48 -> 55, size 8 bits
Radius: 56 -> 63, size 8 bits
```

For this parser I defined:

```
from construct import Bitwise, BitStruct, BitsInteger
from construct import Int32sl, Int8ul
BitStruct( "X" / Bytewise(Int32sl),
           "Offset" / BitsInteger(12),
           "Index" / BitsInteger(4),
           "Time" / Bytewise(Int8ul),
           "Radius" / Bytewise(Int8ul),
         )
```

from the folloing bytes:

```
bytearray(b'\xca\x11\x01\x00\x00\x07\xffu')
```

What I get is:

```
Container: 
    X = 70090
    Offset= 0
    Index = 7
    Time = 255
    Radius = 117
```

What I should have gotten is:

```
Container: 
    X = 70090
    Offset = 1792
    Index = 0
    Time = 255
    Radius= 117
```

As you can see, the values of `Offset` and `Index` that I get do not match with the expected values, the rest is correct.

From what I saw, i need to swap the two byes, which contains the `Offset` and `Index` values.

How could I define a struct inside a struct and swap the two bytes as well?

Comment: More help can can if you make your question replicable. Where `BitStruct` is coming from?

Comment: What values are you getting exactly? Since both those values use BitsInteger instead of ByteWise id say that is a very probable area of possible error

Comment: Oh wait, you defined them wrong in your construct, your offset is reading 4 not 12 and viceversa for index

Comment: So you are getting something Offset: 7 ?

Comment: @Mixone, you are correct, the bits values where in the post wrong (fixed it), but in the software they where correct. In addition I added the values I get.

Comment: Well its clearly reading the offset/index bytes \x00\x07 the wrong way around, most likely BitsInteger is reading them as Big Endian instead of Little

Comment: @Mixone, i have the same opinion as you, but i don't know who to solve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By swapping the bytes in `bytearray` and order of the variables in the `BitStruct` I am able to get the correct values.

```
from construct import Bitwise, BitStruct, BitsInteger, Bytewise
from construct import Int32sb, Int8ul

data = bytearray(b'\xca\x11\x01\x00\x00\x07\xffu')
data_reverse = data[::-1]

format = BitStruct( "Radius" / Bytewise(Int8ul),
                    "Time" / Bytewise(Int8ul),
                    "Index" / BitsInteger(4),
                    "Offset" / BitsInteger(12),
                    "X" / Bytewise(Int32sb),
                  )

print(format.parse(data_reverse))
```

return:

```
Container: 
    Radius = 117
    Time = 255
    Index = 0
    Offset = 1792
    X = 70090
```

If someone have a better solution I would be more then happy to hear.

Answer (score 0):

BitsInteger treats as Big Endian by default.

From the documentation on [BitsInteger](https://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/numerics.html)

> Note that little-endianness is only defined for multiples of 8 bits.

You must set default parameter `swapped` to `True`.

> swapped – bool, whether to swap byte order (little endian), default is False (big endian)

As such :

```
BitStruct( "X" / Bytewise(Int32sl),
       "Offset" / BitsInteger(12, swapped=True),
       "Index" / BitsInteger(4, swapped=True),
       "Time" / Bytewise(Int8ul),
       "Radius" / Bytewise(Int8ul),
     )
```

BUT you are not using multiples of 8 so you should just swap around the initial byte array and be done with it.

Comment: I get the following exception:    raise IntegerError("little-endianness is only defined for multiples of 8 bits")
construct.core.IntegerError: little-endianness is only defined for multiples of 8 bits


exception only:
construct.core.IntegerError: little-endianness is only defined for multiples of 8 bits

Comment: Yes well, the issue stems from not being multiples of 8 as well, this is just an explanation on the changing to little, but that error is konda teoubling true

Comment: would it be possible to define a neasted struct, where the second struct is over the two bytes and those bytes to swap?